# Getting sObject Type into lightning component

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning

I am building a generic lightning component that could sit on an account or contact page to display related task data. However it would need to display slightly different data based on object page it is sitting on.

What is the best method to find out what page type a component is on?

Comment: Suggest you accept Santanu's answer instead of mine - that [force:hasSObjectName](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/components_config_for_app_builder_record_home.htm) is much cleaner (though naming it "SObjectName" instead of "SObjectType" adds confusion).

Comment: Thanks Keith for being a good example :) We learn from seniors like you.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can implement `force:hasSObjectName` interface in your lightning component and you can get the name of the sObject type.

```
<aura:component implements="force:hasSObjectName">
  <aura:attribute name="sobjecttype" type="String" default="{!v.sObjectName}"/>
  {!v.sobjecttype}
</aura:component>
```

Comment: Although this is the correct answer, it doesn't work in communities (forceCommunity:hasSObjectName interface does not exist in API 42.0). Check out Keith's answer below if you need to get the record object type for components in communities.

Comment: Good answer (upvoted). I just use v.sObjectName directly and it does the trick. The creation of a new attribute isn't necessary.

Answer (score 7):

I presume you are passing an Id into your component?

You can pass the Id to the server and use the Apex [Id.getSObjectType()](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_id.htm) method to discover the type that you can then pass back.

Or if the set of types is limited, you could use [DescribeSObjectResult.getKeyPrefix()](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_sobject_describe.htm) calls to obtain the key prefixes (the first 3 characters of an Id) for those types and pass those back so your component can do the Id to type translation.