# confused on force:recordData!

Tags: lightning-data-service

while I'm going through the tutorial on Lightning Data Service, I can see that they use force:record data to perform all the CRUD operation and eliminate the need to write apex controller. but I did not understand the following syntax they use for it.

[Please look at this link](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/data_service_create_record.htm)

code:

```
 <aura:attribute name="newContact" type="Object"/>
<aura:attribute name="simpleNewContact" type="Object"/>
<aura:attribute name="newContactError" type="String"/>

<aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doInit}"/>

<force:recordData aura:id="contactRecordCreator" 
                  layoutType="FULL"
                  targetRecord="{!v.newContact}"
                  targetFields="{!v.simpleNewContact}"
                  targetError="{!v.newContactError}" />
```

My question is:  why are we defining two attributes namely newContact and simpleNewContact of type "Object" and assigning newContact in targetRecord and and simpleNewContact in targetField and why not use a single attribute named simpleNewContact alone.what is the purpose of newContact. also I'm searching for the definition targetRecord,targetFields,targetError please provide any link that explains in detail.

Comment: This change was introduced when the Dataservice was out from pilot .Using the targetRecord the syntax was too longer and the targetFields simplified it further .Recommend using targetFields and you can drop the tragetRecord .

Comment: Hi Mohith Shrivastava,

Thank you. So we can ignore the attribute target Record and we not create the attribute called newContact. Please confirm.

Comment: @MohithShrivastava I think your comment is better than my answer so would be worth posting as an answer that can be accepted...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is some description of `targetFields` in the [Lightning Data Service (Beta)](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/summer17/release-notes/rn_lightning_data_service.htm) release notes:

> force:recordData includes a new attribute called targetFields, which
>   is populated with a simplified view of the record’s fields.
>   targetFields is automatically updated whenever Lightning Data Service
>   detects a record change. v.targetFields.Name is equivalent to
>   v.targetRecord.fields.Name.value. A simple way to update
>   force:recordPreview usage to force:recordData is to change references
>   from targetRecord to targetFields.

So its worth setting up this attribute so you have a more convenient way to reference the fields in your component e.g.:

```
v.targetFields.Name
```

instead of:

```
v.targetRecord.fields.Name.value
```

so getting rid of `.fields` and `.value` that would otherwise have to be present in every reference in the markup. Essentially `force:recordData` is keeping two JavaScript data structures in sync for you, where the `targetFields` one is generally easier and cleaner to use in the component markup.

(And it also makes replacing `force:recordPreview` with `force:recordData` simple.)

*PS*

Mohith's comment on your question contains a key point that I didn't know that makes things clearer: "Recommend using targetFields and you can drop the targetRecord". So the point is that targetRecord is only there for backward compatibility and new code is best written using targetFields only. Suggest you prompt him to post that as an answer and accept that answer instead.

Comment: Hi Keith C,
Thank you.But what is the purpose of this target fields. Since I can only see they have assigned a value to it but they haven't used it anywhere.Is it mandatory to assign targetFields when using force:recordData. Please clarify my question.

Comment: @PrasanthSrinivasan See the "PS" in the answer.

Comment: @MohithShrivastava +1 from me.

Answer (score 9):

This change was introduced when the Dataservice was out from pilot .Using the targetRecord the syntax was too longer and the targetFields simplified it further .Recommend using targetFields and you can drop the tragetRecord .targetRecord is kept only for backward compatibility reasons .

Comment: Thank You. now I understood clearly. I have also tried removing targetRecord from my code and it works good.

Answer (score 3):

I was really interested in this question and finally found another valid answer while solving a problem.

I found one major difference between `targetRecord` and `targetFields` that just saved me a couple hours and additional coding:

**targetRecord contains the objects api name.**

```
var myRecord= cmp.get("v.targetRecord");
var sObjectType = myRecord.apiName;
```

What makes it possible to get the **SObjectType** for any **Id** in Lightning. This is so useful and helps to stay away from additional code and apex controllers while writing generic components, especially when [`implements="force:hasSObjectName"`](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/q/172096/2513) is not an option.